# How do I sync a current iPhone to new mac? With no prior itunes backups

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, iphone

I've always synced to iCloud for my backup. I got a macbook pro and would like to sync it with itunes, but not lose my apps and photos and whatnot.

How can i prevent it from erasing everything and just sync what I have?

Comment: Dupe of http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/102498/46541

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "Do you want to erase this iPhone and sync with this iTunes library" mean?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102265/what-does-do-you-want-to-erase-this-iphone-and-sync-with-this-itunes-library-m)